# scp directory and file contents but not subdirectories or their contents

Tags: bash, scp

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
scripts/
├── isRunning.sh
├── logs
│   ├── date.txt
│   └── isRunning.txt
└── monitorUsage.sh
```

I want to `scp` this scripts directory and include the *.sh files, but I don't want to include the logs directory. How can I accomplish this? In order to copy /scripts and the contents, I use `scp -r ~/path/scripts`, but this also recursively copies the logs directory. I don't want to just copy the scripts (i.e., I also want to copy the directory), so `scp ~/path/scripts/*.sh` won't work.

It seems that `rsync` can be used in lieu of `scp`. Perhaps I can use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick pretty simply and effectively:

`rsync -av --exclude 'logs' ~/path/scripts user@host:/dest/dir`

Answer (score 0):

This way:`scp -r [.sh]* user@remote:/destination`

;)